# Which SQL table statistics are used after they are updated when NORECOMPUTE is turned on?

Tags: sql-server, optimization

**Background:**
I have a large table whose values are significantly rewritten with a `switch` ~once a week, but the table's primary key values remain relatively constant. After the `switch`, statistics are guaranteed to be out of date on the table.

A consequence then is that user queries against this table after the `switch` are pretty much guaranteed to need to update statistics. This has lead them to timing out. (User queries have a 30 second time limit; these same queries running with up-to-date statistics complete in <1 second.)

To address this, I'm looking to manage statistics manually by (1) calling `UPDATE STATISTICS` after the  `switch`, and (2) turning on `STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE`. User queries the rest of the week will then potentially use outdated statistics, but that should be fine.

**Question:**
Let's say I turn `STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE` on for this table, have a constant stream of new queries against this table, and I call `UPDATE STATISTICS`. When will the new statistics be used after the `UPDATE STATISTICS` call is made? Will they be used by all queries that execute after the statistics transaction is made?

Put another way, I'm considering a SQL query in two phases: when it is submitted, and when it is executed. The query optimizer is responsible for telling a query which statistics to use. Does the optimizer create the query plan when the query is submitted, or when the query finally executes?

Comment: The optimizer generates the execution plan based on stats at the time of compilation, which is before execution.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-2017#recompiling-execution-plans

`ALTER TABLE` and `UPDATE STATISTICS` commands trigger execution plan recompilation. So seems like the new statistics would be used by all queries executing after either of those procedures.